# Vercel - Next.js 13 - problemas al hacer build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, ts, vercel

Estoy teniendo problemas para desplegar mi app de Next.js 13.4.4 en vercel, yo tenia esta app funcionando anteriormente, y actualice mis endpoints con la nueva estructura dentro de la carpeta app, y tembien implemente un middleware, en mi entorno local todo funciona perfectamente, incluso si intento buildear lo hacer de manera correcta, el problema viene en al intentar desplegar esto en vercel, arrojando este error...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les comparto la imagen del log completo de vercel y tambien los el texto del error por si quieren copiarlo...

```
[11:10:44.589] Running build in San Francisco, USA (West) – sfo1
[11:10:44.641] Cloning github.com/VAB-8350/B-Large (Branch: stagin, Commit: 1c0a7b0)
[11:10:44.648] Skipping build cache, deployment was triggered without cache.
[11:10:45.614] Cloning completed: 972.996ms
[11:10:45.796] Running "vercel build"
[11:10:46.448] Vercel CLI 31.0.1
[11:10:46.782] Installing dependencies...
[11:10:59.483] 
[11:10:59.483] added 345 packages in 12s
[11:10:59.483] 
[11:10:59.484] 129 packages are looking for funding
[11:10:59.484]   run `npm fund` for details
[11:10:59.508] Detected Next.js version: 13.4.4
[11:10:59.513] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
[11:10:59.513] Running "npm run build"
[11:10:59.909] 
[11:10:59.909] > b-large@0.1.0 build
[11:10:59.909] > next build
[11:10:59.909] 
[11:11:00.454] Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
[11:11:00.455] This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
[11:11:00.455] You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
[11:11:00.455] https://nextjs.org/telemetry
[11:11:00.455] 
[11:11:00.580] - info Creating an optimized production build...
[11:11:22.459] - info Compiled successfully
[11:11:22.462] - info Linting and checking validity of types...
[11:11:25.720] 
[11:11:25.720] ./src/Components/Header/Component/DropdownShop/DropdownShop.tsx
[11:11:25.720] 36:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'handleClickOutside'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[11:11:25.720] 
[11:11:25.720] ./src/app/admin/Components/ProductForm/ProductForm.tsx
[11:11:25.721] 88:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getCategories'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[11:11:25.721] 
[11:11:25.721] ./src/app/admin/Components/UpdateProducts/UpdateProducts.tsx
[11:11:25.721] 62:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'handleClickOutside'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
[11:11:25.721] 
[11:11:25.721] info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
[11:11:29.750] - info Collecting page data...
[11:11:30.551] connect
[11:11:30.570] MongoDB Connected
[11:11:30.582] MongoDB Connected
[11:11:30.644] MongoDB Connected
[11:11:30.646] MongoDB Connected
[11:11:30.649] MongoDB Connected
[11:11:30.651] MongoDB Connected
[11:11:31.501] MongoDB Connected
[11:11:31.501] MongoDB Connected
[11:11:47.291] - info Generating static pages (0/13)
[11:11:47.357] - info Generating static pages (3/13)
[11:11:47.419] - info Generating static pages (6/13)
[11:11:47.607] - info Generating static pages (9/13)
[11:11:48.187] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
[11:11:48.187]     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
[11:11:48.187]     at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6571:19)
[11:11:48.187]     at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6545:27)
[11:11:48.187]     at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1211:60
[11:11:48.188]     at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
[11:11:48.188]     at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
[11:11:48.188]     at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
[11:11:48.188]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[11:11:48.197] 
[11:11:48.197] Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
[11:11:48.197] SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
[11:11:48.198]     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
[11:11:48.198]     at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6571:19)
[11:11:48.198]     at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6545:27)
[11:11:48.204]     at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1211:60
[11:11:48.211]     at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
[11:11:48.211]     at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)
[11:11:48.211]     at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
[11:11:48.211]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[11:11:48.212] 
[11:11:48.212] > Export encountered errors on following paths:
[11:11:48.212]  /page: /
[11:11:48.212] - info Generating static pages (13/13)
[11:11:48.272] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Algo que me parece muy raro es que al intentar volver a desplegar otro punto en el que la app funcionaba bien ahora retorna el mismo error al hacer el build, espero que puedan ayudarme, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor agrega todo el error como texto y no como imágen. Agrega también el código de la ruta `/` es decir el index

Comment: Next.js 13 no es como reaccionar no tengo un archivo inicial "index.ts" lo mas similar es un archivo "layout.tsx" esto esta dentro de la carpeta /src/app/ y el codigo de la "Home" esta en /src/app/page.tsx -> por la nueva estructura de archivos de Next.js 13

Comment: El error habla de que hay un problema al hacer el Pre-rendering de la página "/". `Error occurred prerendering page "/".` Te recomiendo leer las posibles causas de este error en el link que te deja el error: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error Cuando digo que compartas el código de index, en realidad me refiero al componente home o la pagina que se abre cuando navegas a a la "home" de tu App